# AWK different order results in totally different behaviour

Tags: awk

Why is this allowed:

```
awk 'BEGIN  {print "emp", temp = 1}'
```

While this is not allowed:

```
awk 'BEGIN  {temp = 1, print "emp"}'
```

Comment: Replace comma with semi colon?

Comment: Also, note that print allow multiple arguments comma separated. But second command does not make sense

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I should use semicolon instead of comma

Comment: @thanasisp `awk 'BEGIN  {print "emp", temp = 2}'` will print `emp 2`, tested with `gawk 5.1.0` and  `awk version 20070501` on a mac.

Comment: @Luuk right, that'll be the case in any awk (or C or....) as the result of an assignment is the value that was assigned, not the succ/fail status of performing the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++, depending on the context, a `,` can be:

1. A sequence point operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type) or
2. A separator used to list items such as function arguments.

In awk the `,` is only ever a separator so while when you write code like this in C (if `print "emp"` was legal C):

```
print "emp", temp = 1
```

it might mean the `,` is a sequence point and so could mean "call `print` with argument `"emp"` then do `temp = 1`" it **never** means that in awk.

In awk, since `print` accepts a comma-separated list of arguments, it always means "call `print` with first argument `"emp"` and second argument the result of `temp = 1`" (which is `1`, the value assigned to `temp`).

So when you write:

```
temp = 1, print "emp"
```

it's simply a syntax error because an assignment doesn't take a comma-separated list on the right hand side and `print` doesn't return a value that can be stored in a variable so you can't say "assign `temp` with the first argument `1` and second argument the result of doing `print "emp"`.